# Memory game: Why Flipping card doesn't work in my code in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a memory game using HTML+CSS+JAVASCRIPT, I can't make cards flipping.
I want to flip a card when clicking. I've tried the official documentation, but I don't know why it doesn't work.
Thanks for helping me with that.
This is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <section class="memory-game">
    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/avocado.svg" alt="Aurelia" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/avocado.svg " alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/artichoke.svg" alt="Aurelia" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/artichoke.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/berries.svg" alt="Vue" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/berries.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/carrot.svg" alt="Vue" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/carrot.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/corn.svg" alt="Angular" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/corn.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/garlic.svg" alt="Angular" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/garlic.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/grapes.svg" alt="Ember" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/grapes.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/grenade.svg" alt="Ember" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/grenade.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/lemon.svg" alt="Backbone" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/lemon.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/melon.svg" alt="Backbone" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/melon.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/orange.svg" alt="React" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/orange.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>
    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="front-face" src="img/papaya.svg" alt="React" />
      <img class="back-face" src="img/papaya.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

and this is my css

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  background: #020F59;
}

.memory-game {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  background-color: transparent;
  perspective: 1000px;

}

.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);

  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.memory-game:hover .memory-card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #3DADF2;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.back-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Leave my your comments or answer to solve the problem,thanks!

Comment: You want flip on mouse hover? What about mobile devices users, how do they flip cards

Comment: I want to flip by clicking in the card. it's a web app I don't wanna bother myself with making it responsive at the moment

Comment: OK. Can we see JS code?

Comment: At the moment, I am at the beginning I didn't use Javascript yet.

Comment: OK let me help you, I will post a simple solution shortly.

Comment: thank you! Could you keep my design and everything (fixing my code) instead of a new solution

Comment: Sure, please post your questions here if you don't understand something in the new code. Then if my answer helped you can mark it as accepted answer. Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This solution works.

I have simply changed your CSS code a little bit and added 3 lines of jQuery.

Don't forget to load the jQuery library in your HTML markup like this :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(".memory-card").click(function() {
    $(".memory-card").removeClass('flipped');
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  background: #020F59;
}

.memory-game {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: transparent;

}

.memory-card {
  cursor:pointer;  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width:300px;height:300px;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;  background: #3DADF2;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.back-face {
transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.memory-card.flipped {
transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <section class="memory-game">
    <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="card front-face" src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/random-dice.jpg" alt="Aurelia" />
      <img class="card back-face" src="https://www.gamasutra.com/db_area/images/news/2018/Jun/320213/supermario64thumb1.jpg " alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>
        <div class="memory-card">
      <img class="card front-face" src="https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/random-dice.jpg" alt="Aurelia" />
      <img class="card back-face" src="https://www.gamasutra.com/db_area/images/news/2018/Jun/320213/supermario64thumb1.jpg " alt="JS Badge" />
    </div>

  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Firstly Thanks for giving me your time. The code works for me and I can flip the card but When I click on a card the other(s) also get flipped.I don't know if you made it like that.But, for my app I need to flip each card by clicking

Comment: oh ok then just remove this line `$(".memory-card").removeClass('flipped');`